# Error clearing a field via migration script

Tags: entries, craft3, migration

I'm using a migration script to clear out the values for a field on one of my entries. The field is an Entry Field and is not required.

So I do this:

```
$product->components = [];
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($product);
```

But I get this error:

> Argument 1 passed to craft\fields\BaseRelationField::_all() must
>   implement interface craft\elements\db\ElementQueryInterface, array
>   given, called in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fields/BaseRelationField.php on
>   line 382

I can clear out other fields, even entry fields, just fine. But this particular one gives me this error every time.

I've also tried the following:

```
$product->components = null;
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($product);
```

And:

```
$product->components = false;
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($product);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm not sure understand the why of it. But here is the how:

```
$product->setFieldValue('components', []);
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($product);
```

I guess setFieldValue() does some other stuff in it that the magic methods do not.

The more you know! :)

Comment: What the freaking heck. That worked. Thanks!